# google maps and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

i am developing an application which makes use of Google maps. Google maps API returns the result with map on new screen but I want to retrieve only the latitude and longitudinal coordinates  .. so please help me with:

1. How to retrieve them
2. How to dynamically send name and address of the location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too broad a question so without further information it is hard to explain.

These link might help:

http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Working-with-Google-Maps-API-in-ASPNET.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Use_of_Google_Map.aspx

Use google and you will find a lot more.